# Format Number String, To Many trailing/numbers/ Zeros

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I have a simple calculation

```
float x = ([_enterValue.text floatValue]);
//known constant number
float y = (My value here);
[_resultTxt setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", x * y]];
```

The resulting `stringWithFormat` has a lot of zeros ie. 1.806700000000

How would I go about formatting this so my `string` is simply something like 1.8

Comment: Do not use stringFormat for decimal numbers shown to a user. You really should use NSNumberFormatter so the number is properly formatted for the user's locale. Many people in Europe, for example, want to see `1,8`, not `1.8`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Maddy, im in UK and we always use the decimal point but thats a good heads up for future apps, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", x * y]
```

The number after the decimal denotes the number of decimal places to be printed.

Comment: Wow that was quick and really helpful! Thanks for explaining it to, will mark as correct when it lets me, plus 1 for fast answer!